# how to get r_member_social permission with linkedIn share api

Tags: linkedin-api

I need use Share API to get read shares or comments, the documents says I need r_member_social permission, how can I get the permission?

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply for partner program for using r_member_social :

https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Comment: I have applied for 5 days，but linkedIn haven't answered. How long will I wait for?

Comment: Mostly they approve within 1-2 weeks

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. We have been approved for the Marketing Developer Program and don't seem to have access to the permission. KPSingh or @刘同彬 , can you confirm that you haven't taken any extra steps beyond joining the partner program and (still) have access to `r_member_social`?

Answer (score 1):

`r_member_social` permission [is closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lms-faq?view=li-lms-2023-08) by LinkedIn for a while:
[image]